# Prevent 'display:table' stacking vertically only on Android

Tags: android, html, css

I have a simple social media menu with a handful of different links. Everything appears as it should in Chrome, Safari, FF, IE, iOS devices, which is:

[image]

but on Android devices, where the icons stack horizontally:

[image]

HTML:

```
<ul id="menu-social">
  <li>link to site</li>
  <li>link to site</li>
  <li>link to site</li>
  <li>link to site</li>
  <li>link to site</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul#menu-social {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  height:40px;
}
ul#menu-social li {
  float:left;
  display: table;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: none;
}
```

Comment: the html you have posted can't be what you are using, can you post the actual html as it may contain the problem?

Comment: Delete the `display: table`

Comment: @LinkinTED the display: table is used to evenly distribute the icons among a variable width since this is on a responsive site.

Comment: Hmm. Setting the list items to `display: table` wouldn't "evenly distribute the icons" like you suggest. The `width: 20%` (together with the `float`) would do that. As @LinkinTED said, you could delete it, and get the same results. You could drop the `float` and set the items to `display: table-cell`. That sould be what you want (if the Android browser supports that.)

Answer (score 0):

You are better off doing something like this with your CSS:

```
ul#menu-social {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height:40px;
  display: table;
  padding: 0;
}
ul#menu-social li {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20%;
}
```

The `ul` gets `display: table` and the list items are `display: table-cell`. That will ensure that the list items site side by side.

Comment: i took this, with the addition of `width:100%` on `ul#menu-social` and everything looks great. thanks for the help!